# how to improve MySQL REGEXP search?

Tags: mysql, regex, performance

Question are,

1.How can I improve the performance of `SELECT` queries in mysql utilizing `REGEXP`?

The table looks like

```
create table `tweets`(
    `id` bigint auto_increment,
    `tweet` varchar(140),
    `time` datetime,
    primary key(`id`)
);
```

Here the following query takes about **0.35 seconds**.

```
select tweet from tweets where tweet regexp '^[abcdef]{1,4}$';
```

1. Will indexing `tweet` make it faster? If so, what type of index should I use?
2. My table engine is `InnoDB`, Is there any other table engine that will become beneficial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to reduce the result set to evaluate against the regular expression before evaluating.  Regular expressions are, for all intents and purposes, impossible to index for.

If I had to come up with a way for this, I would examine patterns that are commonly searched against, and mark them in some indexible way at insert time.  For example if you use the `^[abcdef]{1,4}$` expression to search against a lot, I'd make a boolean column `first4AThruF` and on an insert/ update trigger, update the column to true or false based on whether or not it matched the regular expression.  If I indexed the `first4AThruF` column, and the column had enough selectivity, I could write the query:

```
select tweet from tweets where first4AThruF = true;
```

and this should be pretty zippy.

Other possibilities to consider are full-text queries or LIKE clauses, although in the case mentioned above I don't expect them to work well.

Comment: "Regular expressions are, for all intents and purposes, impossible to index for" <-- well, yes, except when like in this case, the regex engin determines that the first character can only be one of a set, which is the case with that particular pattern. This is a very common regex engine optimization and I'm sure MySQL has that.

Comment: You're sure of that?  I wouldn't be.  It certainly is not mentioned in the documentation or the `regex(7)` page.  You would need to bridge a text search optimizer with a table search optimizer, and considering the complexity of that and the few cases where it might be useful, I really doubt the coders at MySQL did anything of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

If the search you're looking for is at the start of a string, you can use LIKE as a high-level filter then check again with `REGEXP`:

```
select tweet from tweets 
where 
    ( 
      tweet LIKE 'a%' OR
      tweet LIKE 'b%' OR
      tweet LIKE 'c%' OR
      tweet LIKE 'd%' OR
      tweet LIKE 'e%'
    )
    AND LENGTH(tweet) <= 4 -- try taking this line out line too
    AND tweet regexp '^[abcdef]{1,4}$';
```

In spite of being a little convoluted, this should be a lot faster.